# Salesforce .Net Toolkit Issue

Tags: .net, salesforce, toolkit, sfdc

I am using Salesforce .Net toolkit for one of our project. I have declared a static variable for the Salesforce Client

```
private static AuthenticationClient instance = null;
```

I'm initializing this object whenever object is null in my code

```
await instance.UsernamePasswordAsync(client_id, client_secret, user_name, user_password, "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"); //Production
```

I'm getting below error even after successfully authentication whenever I'm trying to Query data from Salesforce

```
var client = new ForceClient(objService.InstanceUrl, objService.AccessToken, objService.ApiVersion);
var result = await client.QueryAsync<T>(soql);
```

Error is

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instanceUrl
```

Anyone who can help me to resolve this issue.